# Should newly added card be displayed above default card on list?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design, payment

This question is regarding payment during checkout.

Say user already has 2 cards (Card A, Card B) in his wallet, and Card A is the default card.

During checkout he decided he wants to use Card C instead so he proceeds to add it. Once he has entered his card details and tap 'Add', where should the newly added card appear on the list of payment methods?

A. Appear top of the list, above the default card

B. Appear right below the default card

C. Appear according to payment processor (i.e.
AMEX, MASTERCARD, VISA)

Comment: There’s no option to render the new card directly the default card? Otherwise it doesn’t matter so much, as long as the new card is in view. Using a fading highlight also can help recognising newly added elements in a list.

Comment: Let the users place theor new card in the priority list while they're adding it.

Answer (score 1):

What about ordering the cards based on date added? This allows them to determine older vs newer cards quickly (be worth testing the ordering, check what is common amongst other sites too, reduce the learning curve if they are use to a certain ordering).

Where is the add card button initially? If at the bottom/top of the list, then adding the new card to the bottom/top of the list would also be in proximity of the action initially selected.

The card should also appear selected by default, highlighting the new card in the list in its logical place at the start/end.

Does default need to be at the top? A clear label and the fact it would be auto-selected (I assume) should be enough assuming most customers won't have a long list of cards (Check data for this).

I hope some of those ideas help!

Comment: Thanks Blayne, very helpful ideas!